# RVM set per user ruby versions

Tags: ruby, rvm

How would you setup RVM, so that some users automatically get one version of ruby, while others get a different version of ruby?

For example, I want the following users to always have these version of ruby

git => 1.9
root => system
bob  => 2.0

Looking at [the rvm documenation](http://rvm.io/), I can't find any referernce to per user settings.

How could I accomplish this?

I'm hoping there is a config file that can be placed somewhere. Because I'm automating the server installation with puppet, running rvm commands by hand isn't feasable.

**Update**

I've installed rvm, using this puppet module, https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/rvm
It appears that all users have access to the rvm command.

Comment: Rvm is supposed to be installed per-user in the first place.

Comment: `rvm` can be installed and configured per user or per system. So either every user is independently setup and configured, or the whole system is and all users use the same configuration. However, I don't believe it has a way to globally administer, *en masse*, the per-user setups.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to make a .rvmrc file for each user's $HOME directory.

http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc

Answer (score 0):

The `maestrodev/rvm` module installs rvm and rubies system wide, then you need to use `rvm:system_user` to add each user to the rvm group

```
rvm::system_user { bturner: ; jdoe: ; jsmith: ; }
```

and as msergeant mentioned, add the .rvmrc to each user' home.